# Doctrine: Bind IN parameters

Tags: php, doctrine, dql

I was wondering if it is possible to bind an array of integers as a parameter, so I could do something like this?

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
                    ->update('blah c')
                    ->set('ignored', true)
                    ->where('id in ?', array(1,2,3,4));
```

I guess that this isn't possible because it actually binds the variables using the database/PDO, which wouldn't support it.

Apologies if I have missed this in the documentation or another question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use like :

```
 ->whereIn('id', array(1, 3, 4, 5));
```

more :

http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/dql-doctrine-query-language